# Repeated insert request for single problem

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to insert new problem information to my database. I am new to sqlite3, so sorry for any mistakes. I am using sqlite3 and python3. 
I am trying to insert new row corresponding to each problem defined by contest_id and problem_id(each pair of contest_id and problem_id refer to a unique problem). But, if corresponding row is already exists, I will keep it as is it.
Here is table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE problems (
    contest_id INT NOT NULL,
    contest_name TEXT,
    problem_id CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    problem_name TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT Problem_info PRIMARY KEY(contest_id, problem_id) )
```

Python script :

```
import sqlite3
import sys

conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

contest_id = (sys.argv)[1]
problem_list_1 = (sys.argv)[2:]
problem_list_2 = list(cur.execute('SELECT problem_id FROM problems WHERE contest_id = '+str(contest_id)).fetchall())
conn.commit()

problem_list = list(set(problem_list_1) - set(problem_list_2))
problem_list.sort()

for problem in problem_list:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO problems (contest_id, contest_name, problem_id, problem_name) VALUES('+str(contest_id)+', "dummy_name"'+', "'+problem+'", "dummy_name")')
    conn.commit()

print(conn.execute('SELECT * FROM problems').fetchall())
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Here are arguments and output pairs in a sequence as I entered :

```
1159 A B C
[(1159, 'dummy_name', 'A', 'dummy_name'), (1159, 'dummy_name', 'B', 'dummy_name'), (1159, 'dummy_name', 'C', 'dummy_name')]
1167 A
[(1159, 'dummy_name', 'A', 'dummy_name'), (1159, 'dummy_name', 'B', 'dummy_name'), (1159, 'dummy_name', 'C', 'dummy_name'), (1167, 'dummy_name', 'A', 'dummy_name')]
1159 D
[(1159, 'dummy_name', 'A', 'dummy_name'), (1159, 'dummy_name', 'B', 'dummy_name'), (1159, 'dummy_name', 'C', 'dummy_name'), (1167, 'dummy_name', 'A', 'dummy_name'), (1159, 'dummy_name', 'D', 'dummy_name')]
1159 A B E
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_contest.py", line 15, in <module>
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO problems (contest_id, contest_name, problem_id, problem_name) VALUES('+str(contest_id)+', "dummy_name"'+', "'+problem+'", "dummy_name")')
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: problems.contest_id, problems.problem_id
```

On repeatition of problem, it looks like that problem_list_2 remain empty due to which this error is occurs.

Comment: Have you tried doing `conn.commit()` before you close the connection?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Table is getting properly updated for new problems. But, I think try-section request is not working properly as it is not fetching anything at all.  problem_list always remains same as actual arguments(as problem_list_2 is empty) which leads to UNIQUE constraint error.

Comment: Solved. Actually problem_list_2 wasn't empty. It was in this format -> [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('E',), ('F',)]. That's why difference of sets was always first set. Thanks for helping !!